# Why is the returned array of a function is twice as large as the input list?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I have created a simple function in python:

```
def func(a,x):
  return a+x*2
```

and then I call it

```
x = [log(1),log(2),log(4),log(5),log(8)]
#Import y data from a file
free= curve_fit(func,np.array(x),np.array(y))[0][0]
yline = func(free,x)
```

The resulting `yline` is twice as long as `x` and is has each element in there twice.

Why is that so?

**Note:**
I'm importing numpy but not scipy or curve_fit

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`x` is a list and in `func` it will be "multiplied by two" (i.e. the number of its elements doubled).

If you want to multiply it by two (i.e. multiply each element), convert it to `np.array` first:

```
x = [log(1),log(2),log(4),log(5),log(8)]
#Import y data from a file
free= curve_fit(func,np.array(x),np.array(y))[0][0]
yline = func(free, np.array(x))
```